# Akka Future Response to a Sender

Tags: scala, akka, future

I came across the following SIP:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html

As I was reading through, I came across this example:

```
def receive = {
  case Request(data) =>
    future {
      val result = transform(data)
      sender ! Response(result)
    }
}
```

There was a description below in that article:

```
>     Capturing sender in the above example is problematic, since it does not return a stable value. It is possible that the future’s body
> is executed at a time when the actor has started processing the next
> Request message which could be originating from a different actor. As
> a result, the Response message of the future might be sent to the
> wrong receiver.
```

I do not fully understand about this line "Capturing the sender in the above example is problematic...." Isn't that the case where in each request to the Actor (Request(data)) would create a Future block?

The creating of that Future block is synchronous which would mean that the sender reference is known at that time. It is only that the execution of that Future block is somehow scheduled to happen at a later point in time.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `sender` is a method and not a val.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def receive = {
  case Request(data) =>
    future {
      val result = transform(data)
      sender ! Response(result)
    }
}
```

Imagine that the line `sender ! Response(result)` is executed after 300 ms, exactly at the same time as the enclosing actor is handling another message, let's call it `M`. Because sender is a def, not a val, it's evaluated every time it's used. This means, that inside the future you've got the sender of the `M` message! You've responded not to the sender of the original message that created the `Future`, but to some other guy. To mitigate this problem you need to close over the *value of the sender() def at the time of creation of the `Future`*. Compare the original code with this:

```
def receive = {
  case Request(data) =>
    val client = sender()
    future {
      val result = transform(data)
      client ! Response(result)
    }
}
```

You have remembered the original sender, so everything is correct.

It's of utmost importance to *NEVER* execute any methods that depend on time (like `sender`) or change the actor's state in an asynchronous manner. If you need to change the actor's state in response to some asynchronous computation, you should send yourself a message from the `future` block.